# numpy vector multiplication speed?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to numpy, and found such strange(as for me) behavior.
I'm implementing logistic regression cost function, here I have 2 column vectors with same dimension and same types(dfloat). y contains bunch of zeros and ones, and a contains float numbers in range (-1, 1).
At some point I should get dot product so I transpose one and multiply them:

```
   x = y.T @ a
```

But when I use

```
   x = y @ a.T
```

occasionally performance decreases about 3 times, while results are the same
Why is this so? Isn't operations are the same? 
Thanks.

Comment: What are the typical shapes of the inputs?

Comment: I don't think these operations are the same.  `y.T @ a` should be same as `(a.T @ y).T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance decreases, *and* you get a very different answer!

For vector multiplication (unlike number multiplication) `a @ b != b @ a`. In your case (assuming column vectors), `a.T @ b` is a *number*, but `a @ b.T` is a full-blown *matrix*! So, if your vectors are both of shape (1, y), the last operation will result in a (y, y) matrix, which may be pretty huge. Of course, it'll take way more time to compute such a matrix (a.k.a. add a whole lot of numbers and produce a whole lot of numbers), than to add a bunch of numbers and *produce one single number*.

That's how matrix (or vector) multiplication works.

Comment: Right, I messed up with matrix dimensions again. Thanks.